# What database is best to use for hundreds of columns?

Tags: database, cassandra, amazon-redshift, bigdata, nosql

We're getting a huge dataset with over 600 columns, TB in size total. I'd been using redshift for most import jobs, but I've had problems importing rows with a total column size over a certain limit. I've thought of a few options.

- Create a surrogate key from a random UUID. Fully normalize the table, because many columns are very sparse. Problem with this is redshift is not really create for foreign key relationships between many tables.
- Only import the fields that look relevant, this is a problem because the business will continue to ask for new fields and I need to reprocess the whole dataset
- Use a different database like Cassandra, Hive, Riak. But aren't these DBs more like key value stores?

Any experiences you can share in solving this kind of problem is appreciated.

Comment: How do I ask this question without it being opinion based?

Comment: Google BigQuery. 10,000 column limit, 100MB maximum row size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, limit of columns count is not the only reason of selecting the database. It is more about use-case and business scenarios. 
As for Cassandra, it allows to have 2 billion of cells (rows x columns) in a single partition. But, you're right, Cassandra is more like key-value store. 
 
Hive is not key-value store. Imagine, that you get csv file placed in the distributed filesystem, able to process multiple csv files in parallel. It's all about Hive. Hive also provides SQL-like language for queries (HQL) and deployed in the Hadoop infrastructure. 
600 columns would be OK for Hive, even more than 1K columns. The limitation would also depend on storage file format (ORC ot text) and it could cause OOM here.
Riak is a key-value also, but I had no much experience here. 
Anyway, to summarize, the DB should be selected based on use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Amazon Redshift [CREATE TABLE usage notes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_usage.html):

> **Limits**
>
> The maximum number of columns you can define in a single table is **1,600**.
>
> **Wide Tables**
>
> The maximum width of a table with **fixed width columns**, such as CHAR, is 64KB - 1 (or **65535 bytes**). If at table includes VARCHAR columns, the table can have a larger declared width without returning an error because VARCHARS columns do not contribute their full declared width to the calculated query-processing limit. The effective query-processing limit with VARCHAR columns will vary based on a number of factors.
>
> If a table is too wide for inserting or selecting, you will receive the following error: `The combined length of columns processed in the SQL statement exceeded the query-processing limit of 65535 characters (pid:7627)`

So, your desire for **600 columns** is quite okay. You might have to modify field types to stay within the 64KB row limit.

Comment: I hit the 65535 character limit.

Comment: I would go with SQL Server.  You can have 1,024 columns in a table.  I'll tell you right now, I wouldn't want to be the one maintaining this kind of DB!